# Usage: fab mapfile [options] Please specify a valid map file

Tags: python, fabric

When i try to run a simple deploy this message error comes to me:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777

Usage: fab mapfile [options]

Please specify a valid map file.

I am not familiar with fabric. I am Mac os environment ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your `/usr/local/bin` directory set to 777 or world writable. This is very bad, lock it down to 755 and owned by root at the very least.